# SQL Server - Join to void nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

Am sorry I couldn't explain the issue clearly. The actual problem is I have transaction table that contains item transactions such as purchase and sales across various location. I need to find the unit purchase cost of all items across all branches. Now, in a given location, all items may not be purchased. At the same time all items would be purchased in the central warehouse. Means, some items are transferred from Warehouse to  locations instead of purchase at the location. In such cases, the unit cost should be picked from the central warehouse purchase data.

Now, I can get the items and purchase cost across each location from the transaction table, given that the item is purchased at the location. My question was, how to fetch the central warehouse price for items that do not have a purchase history in the transaction table and list it along with all other location purchase cost. Why its difficult is, if there is no purchase hist it means i have no item number to search in the central warehouse.

Frankly I do not know how to do this through SQL query in a single go. Hence i did make a master view as first step - containing all branches and items. This is not ideal because the data is so huge as I have around 50 locations and 200K items resulting in 50 x 200k rows. However, it served the purpose of acting as a location-item master.

Second step, I made central warehouse master with item and purchase cost at the warehouse.

Thirdly, queried transaction table to fetch items that has no purchase at specific locations. These item id was linked to location-item master and used a case statement to get, if purchase cost is null then get the cost from warehouse.

Thank you for pointing out the mistakes and for introducing COALESCE.

Table (Tab1) is as  below:

```
┌─────────┐
│ TabCol1 │
├─────────┤
│ 01      │
│ 02      │
│ 03      │
│ 04      │
│ 05      │
└─────────┘
```

I have a table (Tab2 ) with two columns:

```
┌──────┬──────┐
│ Col1 │ Col2 │
├──────┼──────┤
│ 1111 │ 01   │
│ 1111 │ 02   │
│ 1111 │ 03   │
└──────┴──────┘
```

If we join the above table we get:

```
┌─────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ TabCol1 │ Col1 │ Col2 │
├─────────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 01      │ 1111 │ 01   │
│ 02      │ 1111 │ 02   │
│ 03      │ 1111 │ 03   │
│ 04      │ NULL │ NULL │
│ 05      │ NULL │ NULL │
└─────────┴──────┴──────┘
```

What I need is, instead of `NULL`, I must get `1111`:

```
┌─────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ TabCol1 │ Col1 │ Col2 │
├─────────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 01      │ 1111 │ 01   │
│ 02      │ 1111 │ 02   │
│ 03      │ 1111 │ 03   │
│ 04      │ 1111 │ 04   │
│ 05      │ 1111 │ 05   │
└─────────┴──────┴──────┘
```

In other words, I need to make a master table, with all `COL1` filled to avoid `NULL`.

Comment: is '1111' some "default-instead-nothing" value?

Comment: Use LAG Function

Comment: 11111 is not default. Lets say 1111 is the item number and 01 02 03 etc are the branchs. So item number repeat for each branch. The issue is, some branches does not have certain item number. My goal is to prepare a master Branch-Item table , such that if item does not exist in one branch but available in another, then SQL should list that item number to the branch that does not have it.

Comment: `Col2` will also have two `NULL` values, same as `Col1`. And it seems from your example that you want them replaced by the value from `TabCol1`.

Comment: tabcol1 and col2 are left linked, hence col2 will not be null. only last two rows of col1  will be NULL. And yes, i need it replaced with 1111. Again 1111 is not default.

Comment: @isha, I still don't get exactly what you want, but I believe that you should improve schema prior querying to DB with poor design

Comment: `Col2` will absolutely be `NULL`, **because it is left joined**. Try it and you will see. And it doesn't make sense to want it in the results since it has the same values as `TabCol1`, but I left it there for you in my answer.

Comment: Can you provide an example where `null` is replaced by a value other than `11111`?  If you can explain a bit more about your branches and how they work it would help.

Comment: Hi. Clarify via post edits, not comments. Please read & act on [mcve]. You are not clear about what you want. Your comments are also not clear. Do you mean you want the nulls from a left join replaced by '1111'? Are they ever replaced by other values? Use enough words & sentences to explain exactly what rows go in the desired result in terms of the rows in the inputs.

Comment: This whole story you added to your question helps us have a better idea of what you're trying to do, but doesn't really help us help you with the query. We don't need that story, it can be shortened to a couple of lines. Our answers work perfectly with your example and give the expected results, but it looks like the example doesn't really represent your data structure well enough. If our answers don't give you what you want, then what we need to help you is the actual structure of your tables.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.  Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. PS Adding to RacilHilan's comment: Knowing your story would help us design base tables & queries. But 1. You don't connect it to your tables or query so it is of no use. 2. You already know what the result should look like in terms of the tables, but you still aren't saying.

Comment: Here is how to specify a result in terms of rows in base tables: Give a statement template parameterized by column names --*(characteristic) predicate*--that every row in the result makes into a true statement and that every row (with those columns) not in the result makes into a false statement. Eg we know `(TabCol1, Col1, Col2)` is `IN` the `LEFT JOIN` when `(TabCol1) IN Tab1 AND (Col1, Col2) in Tab2 AND TabCol1=Col2 OR (TabCol1) IN Tab1 AND Col1=NULL AND Col2=NULL AND NOT there's Col1 & Col2 where [(Col1, Col2) IN Tab2 AND TabCol1=Col2]`. So--when is `(TabCol1, Col1, Col2)` in your result?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve makes completely no sense to me, but there's one way to get that result:

```
select T1.TabCol1,
       coalesce(T2.Col1, '1111'),
       coalesce(T2.Col2, T1.TabCol1)
from Tab1 T1 left join Tab2 T2 on T1.TabCol1 = T2.Col2
```

Comment: You need to give column names for the selected columns. PS Please don't answer unclear questions; downvote, close vote & comment asking for clarity. Also, if this is what they want, it's a duplicate question that should be linked & close voted not answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `NULL`s with whatever you want:

```
SELECT TabCol1, ISNULL(Col1, '1111') AS Col1, ISNULL(Col2, TabCol1) AS Col2
FROM Tab2
LEFT JOIN Tab1 ON Tab1.TabCol1 = Tab2.Col2
```

Note that `ISNULL` only works in SQL Server. Alternatively, you can use `COALESCE` which is supported by most databases:

```
SELECT TabCol1, COALESCE(Col1, '1111') AS Col1, COALESCE(Col2, TabCol1) AS Col2
FROM Tab2
LEFT JOIN Tab1 ON Tab1.TabCol1 = Tab2.Col2
```